# Ошибка в Mega SDK для Python

Tags: c++, python, ubuntu, python-3.x, build

> Баг бы исправлен: https://github.com/meganz/sdk/issues/552

Ошибка при использовании [Mega SDK](https://github.com/meganz/sdk) для `Python` v3

Пример сборки:

```
git clone https://github.com/meganz/sdk
cd ./sdk/

sh autogen.sh
./configure --disable-silent-rules \
--enable-python \
--disable-examples \
--with-python3

make
sudo make install
cd bindings/python/
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
cd dist/
pip3 install megasdk-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
python3 ../test_libmega.py
```

Описание ошибки:

```
>>> import mega
>>> mega.MegaApi('test')
AttributeError: module 'mega' has no attribute 'MegaApi'
```

Хотя скрипт `test_libmega.py` отрабатывает, скорее всего ошибка в моей невнимательности, хотя вроде следовал документации с `github`.

ОС GNU/Linux Ubuntu, Python v3.5.2

Comment: Посмотрите на `mega.__file__` (что ожидаемый модуль подцепился). Рабочую директорию смените (`cd`).

Comment: @jfs очень странно но SDK нормально работает если импортировать: `from mega import mega`, возможно ошибка документации.